# Permissions for printing applet

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, printing, applet

I want to print applet. There are two ways:

- Signing applet
- Add `permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "queuePrintJob";` in `java.policy` file

I want to go with second option.
My questions are:

1. Where should I add java.policy file?..on client machine or server?
2. On server I can add it in startup script but if on client machine then how?
3. Can I set permissions in applet code itself?

Comment: 1) On client machine (which is what makes policy files completely impractical) 2) Irrelevant given 1)

Comment: how can i set permissions for printing applet on client machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to print applet. There are two ways:

No, there are at least 3.  The two you mentioned (the 2nd of which is impractical for general distribution), as well as the JNLP API based `PrintService` available to embedded applets launched using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) in a [next-generation-plugin](/questions/tagged/next-generation-plugin) JRE.  Here is a [demo. of the `PrintService`](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps).

I recommend the last one.  It does not require the applet to be digitally signed or trusted, instead the user is prompted when the applet goes to print.

Comment: I cannot launch it via Java web start.My applet is embedded in struts application.

Comment: Which part of *"available to **embedded** applets"* do you not understand?  Covered in greater detail in the JWS link.  If I write anything you do not understand, please ask.